# Does anyone know if/ where I can download shapefiles for bus routes in Cardiff?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk, public-transport

Had a look on OSM and various sources on google, however, there does not appear to be any obvious websites.

I specially want the number 52 bus route for this current task but if there is a general mechanism or website with other routes on this will be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not publicly noted, it would appear that all the shapefiles are available in GEOJSON format at urls with the following structure:

`https://ccts.arcticapi.com/network/operators/CB/lines/<linenumber>/shapes`

For instance, `https://ccts.arcticapi.com/network/operators/CB/lines/9A/shapes` and `https://ccts.arcticapi.com/network/operators/CB/lines/4/shapes` for lines 9A and 4, respectively. The specific shapefile for the #52 line requested is located [here](https://ccts.arcticapi.com/network/operators/CB/lines/52/shapes)

This is a good example of data that is effectively public but not explicitly published, and a formal request to include it in https://foi.cardiff.gov.uk/eng/Pages/OpenData_All.aspx or another appropriate public open data portal may be prudent.